# Token not generate after login with angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am trying to use the OAuth2 library (angular-oauth2-oidc) for authentication with aws cognito.
When I launch my app, I got the default login page of AwsCognito well, but when I enter login/password I got a loop page (token not generated). The value of hasValidAccesToken is already false
This is the loop URL that I got after logging:

```
http://localhost:4200/?code=cfb39cc7-936d-4a0d-a176-d796c080dda2&state=Y01hS0dyeXpWY35-Yk9sfmVvZjRiRFhoNWF4cGN4TUlZU2JCOUdLS1VMeUE5
```

Below my code :

Guards.ts

```
canActivate() {
   if (!this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

login.ts

```
constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService, private configService: ConfigService, private router: Router) {  
    this.oauthService.configure(this.loadConfig());
    this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();

    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin().then(() => {
     if (!this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken()) {
       this.oauthService.initCodeFlow();
     }
   });
     this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
  }

private loadConfig() {
    let authConfiguration: AuthConfig = {};
    authConfiguration.clientId = this.configService.config['clientId'];
    authConfiguration.issuer = this.configService.config['issuer'];
    authConfiguration.clientId = this.configService.config['clientId']; // The "Auth Code + PKCE" client
    authConfiguration.responseType = this.configService.config['responseType'];
    authConfiguration.redirectUri = window.location.origin +'/home';
    authConfiguration.scope = this.configService.config['scope']; // Ask offline_access to support refresh token refreshes
    authConfiguration.useSilentRefresh = this.configService.config['useSilentRefresh']; // Needed for Code Flow to suggest using iframe-based refreshes
    authConfiguration.silentRefreshTimeout = this.configService.config['silentRefreshTimeout']; // For faster testing
    authConfiguration.sessionChecksEnabled = this.configService.config['sessionChecksEnabled'];
    authConfiguration.showDebugInformation = this.configService.config['showDebugInformation']; // Also requires enabling "Verbose" level in devtools
    authConfiguration.clearHashAfterLogin = this.configService.config['clearHashAfterLogin']; // https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/457#issuecomment-431807040;
    authConfiguration.nonceStateSeparator = this.configService.config['nonceStateSeparator']; // Real semicolon gets mangled by IdentityServer's URI encoding;
    authConfiguration.strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation = this.configService.config['strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation'];

    return authConfiguration;
  }
```

config.json

```
{
    "issuer": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_XXXXXXX",
    "clientId": "3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2uc",
    "responseType": "code",
    "scope": "openid profile",
    "useSilentRefresh": true,
    "silentRefreshTimeout": 5000,
    "sessionChecksEnabled": true,
    "showDebugInformation": true,
    "clearHashAfterLogin": false,
    "nonceStateSeparator": "semicolon",
    "strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation": false,
    "AlwaysIncludeuserClaimsInIdToken": true
}
```

Someone have idea for this issues?

Answer (score 0):

Which flow are you trying to use? Your config defines `"responseType": "code",` which suggests a Code Flow.

Then, in your code you do `this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow()` which make the app try to log in using the implicit flow.

Depending on how your IdP is configured and which flow you want to use, either change responseType to token, or use the `this.oauthService.initCodeFlow()`.

Comment: Thanks, I update my code and change to initCodeFlow() but I got the same issues .. Page loop after login with url http://localhos:4200/?code=xxxxxxxx .

Comment: Hi, the problem could be the angular routing, maybe an async guard could help you, take a look at https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/1023#issuecomment-777872258